# Issue in open new tab window for Google Chrome Browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting issue in opening a new tab window using JavaScript. Below is the JavaScript that I have using and its working fine in all other browsers except Chrome.

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Anyone please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: Is it not blocking pop-ups by default? Do you get an error in your console or a message around the address bar saying that popups are blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Due to security measures window.open should be triggered on some user some action e.g. on click.

```
$("#some_link").click(function(evt) {
    var window.open(url, '_blank');win.focus();
});
```

So that new browser window opens only if user wants to do that.

Other browsers may also block popup windows unless you set popup blocker options not to do that.

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/pVcU5/1/)